# Adding a unit to y axis labels in plotly.js

Tags: plotly.js

I'd like to add a unit to the y-axis tick labels in plotly.js. How might I do this? Adding a ticktext and tickval property for yaxis layout doesn't seem to have the effect I thought, as it does with an xaxis.

Comment: Have you checked the `tickmode` of the yaxis ? the ticktext property should exist according to: https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-yaxis-ticktext

Comment: Got it! Just needed `ticksuffix`

Comment: @Amy Answer your own question with the solution and close the question!

Answer (score 11):

As per your own comment, and per [here](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-yaxis-ticktext)

`ticksuffix(string)`

You can add this as part of the x or y axis option as part of the layout text for your plot.

e.g.

```
var layout = {
    yaxis:
    {
        ticksuffix: "suffix"
    }
};
```

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).